# Rails parse Invalid Date Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im trying to figure out why I keep getting a `invalid date` error for certain dates.

For example:

This works:

```
e = "07/02/2013"
 => "07/02/2013" 
start_date = DateTime.parse(e).beginning_of_day.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
 => "2013-07-01 00:00:00"
end_date = DateTime.parse(e).end_of_day.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
 => "2013-07-02 23:59:59"
```

This returns `ArgumentError: invalid date`

```
 e = "07/18/2013"
=> "07/18/2013" 
start_date = DateTime.parse(e).beginning_of_day.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
ArgumentError: invalid date
from (irb):53:in `parse'
end_date = DateTime.parse(e).end_of_day.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
ArgumentError: invalid date
from (irb):55:in `parse'
```

I am using the same date format in both cases. What may be the cause of this/What do I need to change to fix it?

Comment: See @ErminDedovic answer. And notice that in your "7/2/2013" example,  your `strftime` output is "2013-07-02" for a "%Y-%d-%m" format, which isn't what you wanted (*i.e.*, it doesn't really "work" as you indicated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of the date is dd/mm/yyyy. You are trying to create date which is 7th day of the 18th month of 2013.

You can use [strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) if you want to customize your date format.